# How do i optimize the size of socket message i am sending , without missing any data?

Tags: c, sockets

My question is like this
below is the structure which i have to populate and send it through socket

```
struct Mystruct
{
    int numofarray1elements;
    array1[50]; 
    int numofarray2elements;
    array2[25];
};
```

Here size of 1 array1 member is 1024 bytes i.e total size of array1 = 50*1024 = 51200 bytes
size of 1 member of array2 is say 500 so total size of array2 = 12500 bytes

whenever i use send api of socket(unix domain socket) i have to send 51200+12500 +4+4 = 63708 bytes

Problem is i have to send entire size of structure even if i have very less
numofarray1elements, and numofarray2elements
this leads to performance issue
where in almost cases my original data can be less than 10kb but i end up sending 63k everytime

i cannot keep dynamic arrays as its socket message 
i have already otimized my data strutures , array1 must have max 50 elements
array2 must have max 25 elements.

now is there any way that i can send exact data which i have populated?

please provide some method if any

Thanks

Comment: It's totally about your protocol design. Make packets of different sizes in the first place. You can have more than just one `struct` for that.

Comment: Don't use `structs` as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. In this case you will want to send a count ahead of each array, and then only as many array elements as are actually present.

Comment: Are you planning to use UDP or TCP?  The answer to your question will be different depending on this.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner He said he's using unix domain sockets, so neither apply. Datagram or stream, now...

Comment: Ah, I missed that, thanks.

Comment: NB This does not compile. No datatype is given for the arrays.

Comment: Are you using datagram (SOCK_DGRAM) or stream (SOCK_STREAM) type of unix domain socket (AF_UNIX)? With SOCK_DGRAM you probably want send the message within one datagram?

Comment: i am using SOCK_DGRAM, yes i need to send it in 1 packet itself.

Comment: it is very common, especially as the buffer to send gets over approx 1600 bytes, for the call to read() to only obtain part of the full buffer. So have to (often) read data in a loop, utilizing a sliding window as to where the data is to be read into. Note: This is a very good reason to have the first field in the packet buffer to be the total length of the packet. Then use the call to `read()`, including checking the returned values to determine if the code needs to loop again to obtain the full packet

Answer (score 1):

Actually the way for doing it is to have messages of variable length. One of the methods is to use a single array with undefined size as the last element of the struct. Depending on the types of the messages it could be represented by messages or by bytes, e.g.

```
struct Mystruct
{
    int numofarray1elements;
    int numofarray2elements;
    char array[];
};
```

The size of your struct can be calculated as the size of static fields plus sizes needed for actual payload as this:

```
 int packetSize = (sizeof(struct Mystruct) + n1 * sizeof(el1) + n2 * sizeof(el2));
```

now you can use it to allocate the struct and send the packet in a single operation.

```
  struct Mystruct *packet = malloc(packetSize);
  // assign packet fields
  ...
  write(fd, packet, packetSize);
```

Here is a simple example which emulates a version of write/read. It will work if writer and reader have the same endian order. It also assumes that the packet size is sent separately an is known to the reader.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct Mystruct {
    int numofarray1elements;
    int numofarray2elements;
    char payload[];
};

struct Element1 {
    int len;
    char name[30];
};

struct Element2 {
    char name[20];
    int len;
};

// reader emulation
void readData(int packetSize, char *dataIn) {
    union {
        char data[packetSize];
        struct Mystruct packet;
    } dataUnion;
    int i;
    struct Element1 *e1 = NULL;
    struct Element2 *e2 = NULL;

    memcpy(dataUnion.data, dataIn, packetSize);

    printf("Read data e1 size is %d, e2 size is %d\n",
           dataUnion.packet.numofarray1elements, dataUnion.packet.numofarray2elements);
    e1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Element1) * dataUnion.packet.numofarray1elements);
    e2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Element2) * dataUnion.packet.numofarray2elements);
    memcpy(e1, dataUnion.packet.payload, sizeof(struct Element1) *  dataUnion.packet.numofarray1elements);
    memcpy(e2, dataUnion.packet.payload + sizeof(struct Element1) *  dataUnion.packet.numofarray1elements,
           sizeof(struct Element2) *  dataUnion.packet.numofarray2elements);

    for (i = 0; i < dataUnion.packet.numofarray1elements; i++) {
        printf("e1[%d].len = %d, name = %s\n", i, e1[i].len, e1[i].name);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < dataUnion.packet.numofarray2elements; i++) {
        printf("e2[%d].len = %d, name = %s\n", i, e2[i].len, e2[i].name);
    }

}

void main() {
    struct Element1 e1[4];
    struct Element2 e2[8];
    int i;
    int packetSize;
    struct Mystruct *packet = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sprintf(e1[i].name, "e1:%d", i);
        e1[i].len = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sprintf(e2[i].name, "e2:%d", i);
        e2[i].len = i;
    }

    // emulated write data
    packetSize = (sizeof(struct Mystruct) + sizeof(e1) + sizeof(e2));
    packet = malloc(packetSize);
    packet->numofarray1elements = 4;
    packet->numofarray2elements = 8;
    memcpy(packet->payload, &e1, sizeof(e1));
    memcpy(packet->payload + sizeof e1, &e2, sizeof(e2));

    // here you do write data, e.g. write(socFd, packet, packetSize);

    // emulate read data
    readData(packetSize, (char*)packet);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, you mean that i need to allocate the memory for array1 and array2?

Comment: you need to allocate memory for the actual number of elements in array1 + array2. Also you need memory for the size fields in the struct: `(sizeof(struct Mystruct) + n1 * sizeof(el1) + n2 * sizeof(el2))`. This will be the size of your packet. Now you can set values of the size fields and copy your arrays into the bytes of the `array`. You read the whole packet then and do an opposite operation.

Comment: I edited the reply with the information form the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using structures, use TLV mechanism. So for your solution: you can use Type , , Count of Type, Length , Value.

1. Define types which is known at both receiver and sender side
2. Define your message structure as 
   Type taking 2 bytes, Count-of-type taking 2 or 4 bytes , Length taking 4 bytes and Value.
3. This is extensible as you can add any number of types in future as long as the type is known at both side. At receiver side if type is not known, they can ignore that TLV.

Answer (score -1):

You should not send `structs` over network protocols (or store them in files, etc). You need to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) them.

But to solve your problem, simply change your send code:

```
//this is what your code looks like, I assume:
write(sockFd, myStructVariable, sizeof(struct MyStruct));
```

to:

```
//be aware of writev(2) if you want to send these in one system call at once, or copy them into one buffer
write(sockFd, myStructVariable.numofarray1elements, sizeof(int));
write(sockFd, myStructVariable.array1, sizeof(MyArray1) * myStructVariable.numofarray1elements);
write(sockFd, myStructVariable.numofarray2elements, sizeof(int));
write(sockFd, myStructVariable.array2, sizeof(MyArray2) * myStructVariable.numofarray2elements);
```

or something similar

Then change your receive code:

```
read(sockFd, myStructVariable.numofarray1elements, sizeof(int));
read(sockFd, myStructVariable.array1, sizeof(MyArray1) * myStructVariable.numofarray1elements);
read(sockFd, myStructVariable.numofarray2elements, sizeof(int));
read(sockFd, myStructVariable.array2, sizeof(MyArray2) * myStructVariable.numofarray2elements);
```

of course, you could also leave the array and counts defined locally and send those instead. Make sure you check for errors, short reads, etc

Take a look at [flatbuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers) as well, this lets you write structures that come with serialization functions

Comment: I diidn't say you can't. I said "don't". Your code is incorrect in both directions, and ignores short reads, end of stream, and errors. I don't wish to be associated with it in any way.

Comment: sorry about that, knew i forgot something

Comment: Thanks but the problem is i have to send everything in one send and read it in one shot, other wise i need to reassemble the data on the receiving end.

Comment: That's what you have to do. Or, you can read into a buffer with a size of lets say 64K, then copy into each field. Take a look at `fmemopen(3)` or `open_memstream(3)`, or if you are in C++, `std::stringstream`